# Omnet++: unknown parameter. Cannot use module parameters in simulations

Tags: c++, .net, ini, omnet++

So I'm trying create a simple simulation in omnetpp, and I am having trouble with module parameters.

I have provided a simple example to demonstrate my problem. **If I leave the commented sections in all the code commented, the simulation runs fine. If I un-comment the commented sections in all the code, my program compiles fine, but the simulation won't run.** The debug output prints the following message:

*Error in module (omnetpp::cModule) net (id=1) during network setup: (transceiver): unknown parameter `what'.*

I don't know what the issue is, since 'what' is defined in my .ini file and my .ned. Here is my code:

**transceiver.cc**

```
#include <omnetpp.h>

using namespace omnetpp;


class transceiver : public cSimpleModule
{

    private:
        //int what;

    public:
        transceiver();
        virtual ~transceiver();

    protected:
        virtual void initialize() override;
        virtual void handleMessage(cMessage* msg) override;
};

Define_Module(transceiver);

transceiver::transceiver() {
    //what = par("what");
}

transceiver::~transceiver() {

}

void transceiver::initialize() {
    cMessage* msg = new cMessage("Message");
    send(msg, "out");
}

void transceiver::handleMessage(cMessage* msg) {
    EV << "We got a message!" << endl;
    delete msg;
}
```

**package.ned**

```
package packetgenerator;

@license(omnetpp);
```

**omnetpp.ini**

```
[General]
network = transceiver.net
#net.transceiver.what = 5
```

**transceiver.ned**

```
package transceiver;

simple transceiver
{
    parameters:
        //int what = default(2);
    gates:
        input in;
        output out;
}


network net
{
    submodules:
        transceiver: transceiver;
    connections:
        transceiver.out --> transceiver.in;
}
```

Comment: If it helps, the function call for findPar() within the function par() returns -1, meaning that  the parameters don't exist. I thought I defined them in my .ini file and .ned file though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are **NOT** supposed to access parameters in the constructor of the module. Parameters should be accessed in the `initalize()` method.

Use

```
transceiver::initialize(int stage) {
    what = par("what");
}
```

instead of

```
transceiver::transceiver() {
    what = par("what");
}
```

Comment: Are those code segments meant to be swapped around? You say "don't access parameters in the constructor of the module", but you say to use the class constructor instead of the initialize() method.